# NsurlConnections with IPv6 getaddrinfo

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsurlconnection, ipv6

Using NsurlConnections develop the app. how can supporting ipV6 standard networking APIs.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

here read this document can't get how to use this **getaddrinfo** method. how to use this code in application. Exactly what to do and how to implement IPv6 in NsurlConnections. Help me!!!! Thanks advance....

Comment: NSURLConnection is deprecated. you should use NSURLSession instead.

Comment: IPv4 and IPV6 both should support in  nsurlconnection... how is possible

Comment: are you using IP Address literals? If so and IPV4 literal is needed to be translated to IPV6

Comment: @hariszaman [Don't use IP address literals.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW23)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using higher-level APIs, they should just work, and synthesize addresses as necessary. You shouldn't have to use `getaddrinfo`.